# jQuery lightbox showing direct pics

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I have a problem with jQuery lightbox. On previous project it worked but in this it showing direcly picture (not in lightbox frame, but directly like 'image.JPG' in my browser). Can you

PS ('existingid' is a id which really exist in code :) )

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="pl"/>
        <meta name="Keywords" content="folky"/>
        <meta name="description" content="FOLKY"/>
        <meta name="robots" content="index,follow,all"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://adres.ko/reset.css"/>   
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://adres.ko/style.css"/>
        <link rel="Shortcut icon" href="http://adres.ko/image/favicon.ico"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://adres.ko/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css"/> 
        <script src='http://adres.ko/js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js'></script>
        <script src='http://adres.ko/js/jquery.color-RGBa-patch.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://adres.ko/js/jquery-2.0.2.min.js'></script>
    </head>

    <body>  
        <?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/text.php'?>
        <div id="top">
            <div class="white">
                <div class="content">
                    <a href="localhost/"><img class="logo" src="http://adres.ko/image/logo.png"/></a>
                    <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/menu.php')?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="top-bottom">
            </div>
        </div>
```

and the php:

```
<?php $title='Tutke';
$menuclass1="active";
$menuclass2=$menuclass3=$menuclass4="";
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/header.php';?>

<div id="content">
    <?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/menuleft.php'?>

    <div class="offercontent">
        <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#existingid a').lightBox({fixedNavigation:true});
    });
    </script>

        <?php 
            if(!empty ($_GET['category']))
            {
            $category = $_GET['category'];
            $katalog=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/oferta/'.$category.'/';
                $kat=opendir($katalog);
                $ile=0;
                while($plik=readdir($kat))
                    {
                    if($plik!="." && $plik!="..")
                        {
                        $Lista[]=$plik;
                        }
                    }
                $which=1;
                    echo '<div class="ribbon-big-product"><img class="pink_b_l" src="http://adres.ko/image/pink_b_l.png"/><div class="pink_b_c"><div class="pink_b_text">'
                    .$$category.
                    '</div></div><img class="pink_b_r"src="http://adres.ko/image/pink_b_r.png"/></div>';
                foreach($Lista as $Nazwa)
                {
                    if($which!=1) 
                        {echo '<div class="dots">........................................................................................................................................</div>';};

                    include ('oferta/'.$category.'/'.$Nazwa);

                    echo "<div class='product'><div><div><h1>".$ptitle."</h1>".$ptext."</div>";
                    echo "<div class='gallery' id='".$pid."'>";

                            $kataloga=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/oferta/img/'.$pid."/min/";
                            $kata=opendir($kataloga);
                            while($plika=readdir($kata))
                                {
                                if($plika!="." && $plika!=".." && $plika!="...")
                                    {
                                    $Listaa[]=$plika;
                                    $ile++;
                                    }
                                }
                            foreach($Listaa as $Nazwaa)
                            {
                                if($Nazwaa!="Thumbs.db"){
                                echo "<div><a href='http://adres.ko/oferta/img/".$pid."/".$Nazwaa."'><img src='http://adres.ko/oferta/img/".$pid."/min/".$Nazwaa."' alt=''/></a></div>";}

                            };
                            $Listaa="";
                    echo "</div></div><div><img class='image' src='http://adres.ko/oferta/img/".$pid."/".$pimg."'/></div></div>";

                    $which++;
                };
                ;
            }
            else{
            $katalog=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/oferta/polecane/';
                $kat=opendir($katalog);
                $ile=0;
                while($plik=readdir($kat))
                    {
                    if($plik!="." && $plik!="..")
                        {
                        $Lista[]=$plik;
                        }
                    }
                $which=1;
                    echo '<div class="ribbon-big-product"><img class="pink_b_l" src="http://adres.ko/image/pink_b_l.png"/><div class="pink_b_c"><div class="pink_b_text">POLECANE</div></div><img class="pink_b_r"src="http://adres.ko/image/pink_b_r.png"/></div>';
                foreach($Lista as $Nazwa)
                {
                    if($which!=1) 
                        {echo '<div class="dots">........................................................................................................................................</div>';};

                    include ('oferta/polecane/'.$Nazwa);

                    echo "<div class='product'><div><div><h1>".$ptitle."</h1>".$ptext."</div>";
                    echo "<div class='gallery' id='".$pid."'>";

                            $kataloga=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/oferta/img/'.$pid.'/min/';
                            $kata=opendir($kataloga);
                            while($plika=readdir($kata))
                                {
                                if($plika!="." && $plika!=".." && $plika!="...")
                                    {
                                    $Listaa[]=$plika;
                                    $ile++;
                                    }
                                }
                            foreach($Listaa as $Nazwaa)
                            {
                                if($Nazwaa!="Thumbs.db"){
                                echo "<div><a href='http://adres.ko/oferta/img/".$pid."/".$Nazwaa."'><img src='http://adres.ko/oferta/img/".$pid."/min/".$Nazwaa."' alt=''/></a></div>";}

                            };
                            $Listaa="";
                    echo "</div></div><div><img class='image' src='http://adres.ko/oferta/img/".$pid."/".$pimg."'/></div></div>";

                    $which++;
                };
                ;};
            ?>

    </div>


<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/footer.php'?>
```

Help, please

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the order of script inclusion (*include jQuery before including any other script that itself uses jQuery*)

```
 <script type='text/javascript' src='http://adres.ko/js/jquery-2.0.2.min.js'></script>
 <script src='http://adres.ko/js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js'></script>
 <script src='http://adres.ko/js/jquery.color-RGBa-patch.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved - reset.css was blocking LightBox frame